# Set date from model for Datepicker in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, datepicker, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a bootstrap datepicker in my ASP.NET Core MVC application. This works so far. Now I want the start date (for example 20.06.2023) to be taken from my model and displayed and highlighted in the date picker. The date in the past should not be selectable, greyed out.

This is my current datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            startDate: new Date(),
            language: "de"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here I have tried to take the date from the model, but it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dateStart= new Date('@Model.DateStart');

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({    
        startDate: dateStart,        
        language: "de"
    });
});
</script>
```

This is how I implement the datepicker

```
<div class="form-group row">                            
                        <div class="col-sm-3" >                                                                                         
                            <input type="text" asp-for="DateStart" class="form-control" id="datepicker"/>                            
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateStart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And this is the property

```
public string? DateStart{ get; set; }
```

What else do I have to adjust to make it work?
Thank you.

Comment: In what way does the code fail?  When you examine the client-side code, what value was emitted from `@Model.DateStart`?  When you debug the client-side code, what value does `dateStart` have?

Comment: Thank you for the food for thought. With an alert came the message invald date. I changed the German date format to yyyy-MM-dd and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dateStart = "@Model.DateStart";
    var arrayStr = dateStart.split(".");        
    var dateStartNew = new Date(arrayStr[2], arrayStr[1] - 1, arrayStr[0]);         

    if (dateStartNew < Date.now()) {
        dateStartNew = new Date();
    }

    dateStartNew.setDate(dateStartNew.getDate() + 1);

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        startDate: dateStartNew,
        language: "de",
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var startDate = new Date(dateStartNew.getFullYear(), dateStartNew.getMonth(), dateStartNew.getDate());

            if (date.getTime() === dateStartNew.getTime()) {
                return {
                    classes: 'highlighted',
                    tooltip: 'Start Date'
                };
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a input tag with type equal to date:

```
<input id="datepicker" type="date" />
```

Try setting the min attribute like:

```
$("#datepicker").attr("min",dateStart);
```

Comment: You should mention what libraries are needed for this to work.

Comment: Sure.  I used bootstrap and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.
MyDate.cs

```
    public class MyDate
    {
        public string? DateStart { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
       public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var mydate = new MyDate() { DateStart = "2023-06-20" };
            return View(mydate);
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication35.Models.MyDate

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" asp-for="DateStart" class="form-control" id="datepicker" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateStart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<script> 
    var dateStart = new Date("@Model.DateStart");
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        startDate: dateStart,
        defaultDate: dateStart,
    });
</script>
```

Output
[image]